# React state is undefined with binded function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to build a React experiment. I am facing the problem of inaccessible Class.state. The whole code in my CodePen pen: https://codepen.io/Godje/pen/JNQVad

On line 115 you can see me binding `this` to the method:

```
this.generateQuestion = this.generateQuestion.bind(this);
```

On line 200 and 201 I am checking if `this` refers to the App class, not to the function scope. AND IT DOES, BUT not on the `this.state`.

```
console.log(this); //success. Return App object, which HAS "state" key
console.log(this.state); //undefined. Even though, It refers 
                         //to the object that has a "state" key 
                         //it doesn't return it for some reason.
```

I need that state to be accessible. What is the problem?

Comment: It would be much easier if you could provide the exact code snippet here. You don't have to include all of your code.

Comment: I got a version working below, but had to fork the codepen instead of adding a snippet here. It was just a bit too much effort to tease it out. Let me know if you have another question on this.

Comment: @IsaacB it doesn't work. Basicaly, I need the question to be generated multiple times later. In your case, you set `this.generateQuestion` to the RESULT of it. Automatically destroying the method basically. On my pen - the timer works. On yours it doesn't. It is obvious that if the function is called inside the constructor it is going to return the state. But i need the state oustide of the constructor. I binded the function, and IT DOES THE JOB, BUT it just can't take the state of the object for some random reason.

Comment: @Umair the pen matters. And cutting the parts of it will make it really confusing. I putted in the most important parts of the pen. The ones that don't return the `state`. I am not facing any other problems, but the one with taking the key from the object. I just can't take the key from the object for some reason. I take `this` - it returns the object, that has the `state`. When i do `this.state` it says `undefined`. That's it. I can't solve it. And answers below have nice suggestions, but they fix other problems, neither of them solve the `this.state` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written following code in constructor:

```
this.state = {
  gameState: {
    state: "intro",
    quest: this.generateQuestion(),
    score: 0,
    round: 0,
    time: 3
  }
}
```

**generateQuestion** will be called first and after its execution initial state i.e **this.state** will be set in the component, that's why you are getting it undefined.

Comment: but since i have access to `this`. And `this` has `state`. Why can't I access `this.state` then?

Comment: That is due to hoisting mechanism of javascript.
Hoisting is the mechanism of moving the variables and functions declaration to the top of the function scope (or global scope if outside any function).
here is the variable lifecycle:
1.Declaration
2. Initialization
3. Usage
this.state is declared but will be initialized when execution of generateQuestion completes and after that you can use that. Javascript allows us to declare and initialize at the same time like you did. But internally it is following this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing too much binding. I fixed and forked your code ONLY pertaining to the GenerateQuestion function in this  [forked CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvezKM). Normally I would add the code snippet, but with how this is all bound together, I'll just address the concept.

In React, you bind all your functions just as you did in the constructor - with `this.exampleFunction = this.exampleFunction.bind(this);`. From here, you maintain your state by using React's build in setState function (read about it more in [the documentation here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)).

Do not set state by direct definition as you are throughout your code (ex. `this.state.gameState.score = 0;`. And when using setstate, keep in mind that any objects defined int he state will be updates as a whole object (also discussed in the linked documentation).

Most importantly, you lost your bindings when you rebing the functions as you do starting at line 110 and a few other places. This is what was keeping you from accessing the state. You'll notice that I got rid of the additional bindings on `generateQuestion` to get it to work.

Set variables to hold a result you need to act on, such as `let answer = this.handleAnswer();`. Then set anything you need to keep for render purposes to the component state. You can save additional non-render information to the class without worrying about binding like this: `this.additionalAttribute = 'string-in-this-case';`. These additional attributes will not trigger update events - keep that in mind.

Focusing on setting all state following React's recommended `setState` function. And stop rebinding functions to themselves outside of the constructor. Use variables, additional attribute assignments, and most importantly - more state as needed.

Comment: The reason i do `this.state.gameState.score = 0` is because I dont want to update the whole gameState object, just some parts of it.

Comment: React documentation strongly recommends against trying that method. Even if you just want to update one attribute of an object defined in your state - you would want to clone that object, change the attribute, and update the whole object using `setState()` like this: `let gameState = Object.assign({}, this.state.gameState);    gameState.score = 0;    this.setState({ gameState });`.

Comment: Thank you! That is a good idea. Still, the whole didn't solve the problem. I can't access `this.state` even in your pen. I need that state to be accessible. I can't access the state. Considering that, this whole thread didn't make any sense, lol =D

Comment: In the version I forked, this.state printed correctly to the console. To maintain your proper bound states, you just need to apply the changes I made in removing the rebinding of functions to the other related functions.

Answer (score 0):

By running the debugger I found that `console` is displaying a delayed image of **App** object. At the point where `this.state` is called, the `state` within the app is not defined yet, BUT in the process of defining, because we are calling the function and returning value from it WHILE initializing the `state` object. The fix does not fix the problem directly, but rather fixed the problem I face. I changed the function to check if `this.state` exists, and if it doesn't i assign the value of the variable to be the one that should happen at the **first time** of the call (because by the **second** time of the call `this.state` is already **defined and is accessible**).
I will be developing this project further, but for now answer lies in the line `207`:

```
state = this.state ? this.state.gameState.state : "intro";
```

if the state is defined then it will proceed with taking the value of the `gameState`. But if it doesn't, it will take on the value of the "intro", the one that I want it to be at the beginning.
Tested and works.

Thanks to every contributor to this thread.
Thanks to RITESH BANSAL for mentioning the state of the object through parsing of code.